# Access requering combobox VBA

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, combobox

I have bound Access forms that are connected to linked tables.

In the `AfterUpdate` event of `ComboBoxA` I let `ComboBoxB` requery, which is working fine.

However, when I assign a value to `ComboBoxB` and after that change the selection in `ComboBoxA` then I would like to have `ComboBoxB` requery again, as some values might not be allowed anymore (depending on the selection in `ComboBoxA`)

However, at that moment the list in `ComboBoxB` gets refreshed and the new possibilities are shown in the list. The only problem is that the old value that was selected earlier still appears in the ComboBox, so not in the list, but in the actual field.

It is not happening for all my ComboBoxes, but I can't manage to find the difference between those for which the value is not deleted and for those that it is.

I tried

```
Me.ComboBoxB = Null
```

in the `ComboBoxA_AfterUpdate` Event, but that won't work, because the field does not allow Null values.

Does someone have an idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why does the combo not allow null? How about including Please Select as an option? This can be done with a union query.

Comment: Thank you. The field that it is bound to does not allow Null values.

I like your suggestion for Please Select, but I am afraid it won't work in this case, because the form control is bound to an integer (number) field. Or I am wrong in thinking this?

Comment: The union query can run something like Select 0, "Please select" ...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. but i am afraid that i will run the risk that the user actually selects 0, "Please select" and then continue. Coming back to my problem, is it normal that a combox holds its old value after having requered and the old value is not in the item list any more?

Comment: It occurs to me that you have the same name on your field/column as you do on your combobox, this is not a good idea. You should be able to set a bound combo to null. I generally rename all controls.

Comment: Did you try using `Me.ComboBoxB.Text = ""` in the `ComboBoxA` update event ?